# JButton size is set to default size when visibility is changed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, visibility

Like I said the `JButton GR` is set to the default size (size of window) when I click `JButton MN`.
When the program is started the `JButton GR` has the right size (200 by 20), when clicked the menu button appears also at the right size (200 by 20), but when the menu button is clicked the `GR JButton` is at its default size. When the full size `GR JButton` is clicked the Menu button reappears with the right size.
I'm using BlueJ (school dose not allow other IDEs).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class MAIN
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ActionClass actionEvent = new ActionClass();

        //Main window
        JFrame Program1 = new JFrame("Program1");
        Program1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Program1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        Program1.pack();
        Program1.setVisible(true);

        //menu button (returns to home Menu)
        JButton MN = new JButton("MENU");
        MN.setBounds(300, 10, 200, 20);
        MN.setVisible(false);
        Program1.add (MN);
        //MN.setActionCommand("1");

        // Enter GRC
        JButton GR = new JButton("GRC");
        GR.setBounds(300, 40, 200, 20);
        GR.setVisible(true);
        Program1.add (GR);
        //GR.setActionCommand("2");

        GR.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent GRH)
            {
                MN.setVisible(true);
                GR.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
        );

        MN.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent MNH)
            {
                MN.setVisible(false);
                GR.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: `MN.setVisible(true);
                GR.setVisible(false);`  Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: JButtons MN and GR should be declared as local variables or missing final ....

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  And as pointed out by @mKorbel, that code example won't compile as written!  Don't post 'something like' the code being used!

Comment: visibility should be last code line in class

Comment: So that means i have to rewrite the program using layout managers, and layout padding and borders? Or is there a way i can just fix this bug and use it only on one OS?

Answer (score 2):

> Like you said the Jbutton GR is ...

- JFrame has BorderLayout as default LayoutManager in API,
- use Java naming conventions
- use [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead of NullLayout and wrong way
- setVisible(true); should be last code line, because your are in risk that all JComponents are added to already visible container (e.g. mouse over repainting those JComponents)
- use [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

---

- simplest as is possible

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Main {

    private JFrame myProgram1 = new JFrame("myProgram1");
    private JButton myMN = new JButton("MENU");
    private JButton myGR = new JButton("myGRC");

    public Main() {
        myGR.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent myGRH) {
                myMN.setVisible(true);
                myGR.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        myProgram1.add(myMN, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        myMN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent myMNH) {
                myMN.setVisible(false);
                myGR.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        myProgram1.add(myGR, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        myProgram1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myProgram1.pack();
        myProgram1.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}
```